# Chromedriver.exe window showing up even in headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The headless argument only stops the opening of the Chrome browser window still, the **chromedriver.exe** window opens. Is there any way to prevent both windows from opening?

**Webdriver code**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)
NovelBox.scroll(driver)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()
```

**Scroll function**

```
    def scroll(driver):
        last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        while True:
            # Scroll down to bottom
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            # Wait to load page
            time.sleep(1)
            # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
            new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            if new_height == last_height:
                # If heights are the same it will exit the function
                break
            last_height = new_height
```

Comment: Which version of chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? This sounds like a compatibility issue.

Comment: Latest stable release: ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 [https://chromedriver.chromium.org/]

Comment: And which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried removing all other options except `--headless` to see how it reacts? Maybe it is a wonky combination of options causing this.

Comment: Yes I have tried

Comment: Apparently some say the chromedriver.exe window will always open, seems like there is no way to prevent it.

Comment: That should not be true. We are using ChromeDriver.exe in the .NET technology stack and running it with the `--headless` flag does indeed hide the browser window. In fact, I am running automated tests in headless mode without the browser window as I type this comment. Something else is going on.

Comment: Try opening the command line and type `chromedriver --headless` and press ENTER. What happens?

Comment: Also, what happens when you open the command line and type `where chromedriver`? What does it return?

Comment: `chromedriver --headless` chromedriver : The term 'chromedriver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program.

Comment: `where chromedriver` no output

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH\TO\SELENIUM\DRIVER\EXE)
```

Comment: Please feel free to provide explanation of your answer. It is very helpful if you explain why your answer works so that readers are able to understand it correctly.

Comment: I have already added `options.add_argument('--headless')` which is equalent to `options.headless = True`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Python IDLE/Shell. When I run the script through Python IDLE or shell the chromedriver.exe window will be opened. But not in Visual Code or running through the terminal.